# How to select a deep span element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this is kind of a weblog template of mine, that the every post have this HTML:

```
        <div class="box">
        <div class="box2">
            <div class="box-main2"><div class="hole"></div>
                <div class="post"></div>
                <div style="width:100%; height: 32px; padding-top: 0px; position: relative ;">
                        <div class="btn" style="float:left;">more...</div>
                        <div class="info-box" style="float:right;">
                            <div><span class="date">2013, March, 3</span><span class="author">Komeyl</span><span class="comment"><sup>23</sup></span></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-bottom" >
                <div id="commentPanel">


                </div>
                <div class="box-bottom2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

And I want to select comment class in the span tag in order to when user clicks it the commentPanel class slides down from the bottom of the box, and slides up when the next click happened, this should be in a way that each comment class should select its own commentPanel cause there will be lots of comment and commentPanel classes. 
i wrote this jQuery but it wont't work the way I want:

```
$('.comment').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('click');
    $('.box-bottom #commentPanel').slideDown(300);
    $('.box-bottom2:first').show(100);
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('click');
    $('.box-bottom #commentPanel').slideUp(200);
$('.box-bottom2:first').hide(100);
}
);
```

and box-bottom2 class is the bottom picture of the box that should appear and disappear with the commentPanel.

Comment: what jQuery version are u using?

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pLDAU/3/)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function (func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function () {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$('.comment').clickToggle(function () {
    $(this).addClass('click');
    $(this).parents('.box-main2').next('.box-bottom').find('#commentPanel').slideDown(300).next('.box-bottom2:first').show(100);
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass('click');
    $(this).parents('.box-main2').next('.box-bottom').find('#commentPanel').slideUp(200).next('.box-bottom2:first').hide(100);
});
```

or shorter code

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLDAU/5/)

```
$('.comment').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('click');
    $(this).parents('.box-main2').next('.box-bottom').find('#commentPanel').slideToggle(300).next('.box-bottom2:first').toggle(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[edited]**

try this: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/pLDAU/2/)**

```
$('span.comment').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.box2').find('#commentPanel,.box-bottom2').slideToggle();
});
```

add `style="display:none"` to the commentPanel to make it invisible on loading